# Is it possible to combine accent and tremolo in notation?

Tags: notation, dynamics, articulation

I want to have a strings part with tremolo, like used for example on the beginning of the 4th movement in Beethoven's 6th Symphony.

[image]

But I also want the beginning of every such note to be accented. In other words, I'd like the first among those 16th's that are effectively played to be a bit stronger than those following it. So, does it make sense to write an accent sign above tremolo note and will the player understand the intention if i put it like this?

[image]

From what I saw watching the performances, string players indeed already differentiate two tremolo notes by changing their bow's angle against the neck a little bit, even without any accent sign. But since in my piece I change durations of tremolo notes, I need to see if this is the proper way to make this differentiation more distinct.

Comment: That's how I would translate the accent(s).

Comment: There is a natural accent on the first note of a tremolo.

Comment: Yeah, well my only doubt here is how to make that natural accent just a little more accented, which is of course a matter of nuance

Comment: I've used accented grace notes for this purpose, but I'm curious what more authoritative people say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with writing an accent on a tremolo. Musicians will interpret it exactly as you would expect